# TreeView - Clicking at an empty area

Tags: delphi, treeview

How to decide in TreeView's OnClick event, if only an empty area got clicked? Im using the code bellow, but in *CheckNode* i always got a TreeNode instance despite the fact that i only clicked an empty area beside a TreeNode.

```
procedure TfrmDevTree.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPoint;
  CheckNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  GetCursorpos(p);
  p := TreeView1.screentoclient(p);
  CheckNode := TreeView1.GetNodeAt( p.X, p.Y );
  if CheckNode = nil then
    Exit;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I reverted the edit. Please don't add answers in questions. And there's no need for anything more than you to accept the answer. Clearly you can work out how to interpret the hit test info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GetHitTestInfoAt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.GetHitTestInfoAt) method as shown in [this example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/GetHitTestInfoAt_%28Delphi%29):

```
  MyHitTest := TV.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y);
  if htNowhere in MyHitTest then ...
```

Comment: Welcome. Yes of course, you get different results depending on where you click.

Comment: @tdiop I think you should accept this answer. You cannot expect TOndrej to write your program for you. `GetHitTestInfoAt` returns the information you need, now it's up to you to work out what to do with it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because i made some edit, that does not mean i wont accept his answer! Sorry but i dont understand your step. I thought that my edit can save a little time for newbies.

Comment: Answers go in answers, not in questions. Your specific set of conditions isn't that interesting. Everyone will have different needs. For instance, in my code I can see this: `if (htOnLabel in HitTests) or (htOnIcon in HitTests) then` which differs from your chosen test. In fact, if I had been writing the answer then I would not have included a specific test. The answer that I was part way through writing when TOndrej beat me to the punchline did not include a test.